# Truncated sums of symmetric polynomials; reference request for an algebraic derivation

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions, enumerative-combinatorics

EDIT: This is a case of being too wrapped up in a formulation
($e_j,p_i,$ and the like) to try something simple.  It did not
occur to me to pull exp to the outside in the weeks I have 
stared at this.  Thanks to Aaron Meyerowitz and Brendan McKay for
a humbling revelation.  I leave it to others to decide if  this is
an object lesson in mathematical myopia or a question to be removed.
END EDIT

If the following turns out to be a homework question, great!
Just tell me what course, textbook (or online accessible .pdf)
and page number has the problem, and I'll go check it out.

Let $m$ and $k$ be integers with $k \gt e^m \geq 1$. I am 
considering two expressions in variables $x_i$, and looking
at the partial sums with monomials of degree at most $m$,
which I note by $\cong_m$.  (So if any term like, say, $x_hx_i^{m-1}x_j$ occurs
in my sum, I toss that term and consider what is left with $\cong_m$.)
 The question in brief is:
$$\prod_{0 \leq i \leq k}(1 - x_i) \cong_m
\prod_{1 \leq j}(\sum_{0 \leq l} [ - \sum_{0 \leq i \leq k}(x_i)^j/j ]^l/l! ) ?$$

Here is some background and motivation.  I rewrite the above question in terms
of elementary symmetric polynomials in the $x_i, 0\leq i \leq k$.
In order to have enough terms to make sense, assume $k$ is as large as needed.
(Likely I just need $k > e^{e^m}$, but it would be nice to know if, say, just 
$k \gt m^2$ will do.)  Let us write 
$q_j$ for $ \sum_{0 \leq i \leq k} (x_i)^j/j $.  This is $p_j/j$, or the
$jth$ power symmetric polynomial divided by $j$.  Let us also write $XP_m(t)$ for some
polynomial $t$ to be the formal expression (which we will chop off after the
terms get too big) $\sum_{0\leq j \leq m} (-t)^j/j!$, after the series expansion
for $e^{-t}$.  For the left hand side, we rewrite it in terms of the
elementary symmetric polynomials $e_j$, which is the sum over all $j$-sets
(not $j$-tuples) $\{i_1, \ldots , i_j\}$ of $\{0,\ldots,k\}$ of the monomials
$x_{i_1}\ldots x_{i_j}$. I also declare $e_0=1$.
 Now the left hand side is written as a sum, and
as I am concerned only with that part containing monomials of total degree at most $m$,
I can limit the summation indices and 
the question now becomes:

$$\sum_{ 0 \leq i \leq m} (-1)^ie_i \cong_m \prod_{1\leq j \leq m} XP_m(q_j) ?$$

If I had facility with any computer algebra system, I would have tried it there first
before asking here.  I have verified the equality
for small $m$, and would like a reference to a proof, or disproof.
Also, Newton's identities $je_j = \sum_{1\leq i \leq j}(-1)^{i-1}p_ie_{j-i}$ give
me some hope that the above is true, but I have not found a derivation.

My motivation is in exploring the limits of an argument I learned in a paper
of Harlan Stevens.  He uses the left hand side with prime reciprocal values for the
$x_i$, and looks for the smallest odd integer m such that the sum is positive,
but all partial sums for smaller odd positive integers are negative, so in
particular $q_1=p_1\gt 1$ for interesting examples.
If it is true, I hope to show that the smallest odd positive $m$ that gives
a positive partial sum implies $p_1 \gt Cm$ for some real constant $C$, which would
then tell me that this argument is limited to showing upper bounds no tighter than $Ak^{B\log\log k}$,
and no smaller.

Gerhard "Also, I Find It Pretty" Paseman, 2014.01.19

Comment: It occurs to me that this might be in a text like Enumerative Combinatorics or generatingfunctionality.  If someone knows where this is treated, a text and section number would be appreciated.  Gerhard "Lacks Good Web Search Terms" Paseman, 2014.01.19

Comment: DO you know that $k=m$ is not enough?

Comment: Gerhard, unclear, do you have the two books you mention? I think I have both as pdfs. I found the second one already..

Comment: Your first display has "[" once and "]" twice.  Please fix it.

Comment: I don't really get the question.  The right side of your first display is just a rearrangement of $\exp(\sum_i \ln(1-x_i))$ after applying Taylor expansion to the exp and ln functions. When it is formally expanded out, all terms with total degree more than $k$ vanish, as they should by Taylor's theorem.

Comment: Thanks to all for the kind attention.  Hopefully my next question will have more of a challenge.  Gerhard "Really, I Didn't See That" Paseman, 2014.01.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
 $$\prod_{1 \leq j}^{\infty}(\sum_{0 \leq l}^{\infty} [ - \sum_{i=0}^k\frac{x_i^j}{j} ]^l/l! ])=$$
$$\prod_{1 \leq j}^{\infty}\mathop{exp}\left( - \sum_{i=0}^k\frac{x_i^j}{j}\right)=$$
$$\mathop{exp}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left( - \sum_{i=0}^k\frac{x_i^j}{j}\right)\right)=$$
$$\mathop{exp}\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\left( -\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_i^j}{j}\right)\right)=$$
$$\mathop{exp}\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\ln({1-x_i)}\right)=$$
$$=\prod_{i=0}^k(1-x_i
)$$

So I think $m=k$ would be just enough.

Comment: Darn, beat by 3 seconds!

Comment: Oh, it's only that Brendan types faster. Gerhard "You Still Get The Upvote" Paseman, 2014.01.20