# Nilradical and Newton's identities

Tags: polynomials, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-equations

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity such that $n!$ is not a zero-divisor. Let $s_1=\sigma_1,s_2,s_3\cdots$ and $\sigma_1,\sigma_2\cdots$, (convention: if $k>n$, then $\sigma_k=0$) be elements of $R$. We consider the Newton's identities

$s_k=\sigma_1s_{k-1}-\cdots+(-1)^k\sigma_{k-1}s_1+(-1)^kk\sigma_k$.

We assume that there is a zero sequence of length $n$: $s_p=\cdots=s_{p+n-1}=0$.
Formal calculations seem to indicate that the $(\sigma_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ are in the nilradical of $R$. In particular, the result is true for $(n=6,p\leq9),(n=7,p\leq8),(n=8,p\leq 7),(n=9,p\leq5)$.

Is this result true in general ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be interested in a variation presented here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/155114/truncated-sums-of-symmetric-polynomials-reference-request-for-an-algebraic-deri  .  It represents something close to your form as a product, and you might find in it inspiration for a proof that terms for large enough k are in the nilradical.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Myopic Mathematics" Paseman, 2014.04.29

Answer (score 3):

If that helps, in Section III.2 of my article
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00023-003-0127-7
there is a proof due to de Calan and Magnen of the fact: for any $k\ge 1$, $({\rm tr}\ N)^{k(n-1)+1}$
is in the ideal generated by the matrix elements of $N^k$. Here $N$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of indeterminates.

Comment: See also two (I believe) proofs in Doron Zeilberger, *Gert Almkvist's generalization of a mistake of Bourbaki*, http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/gert.html .

Comment: Thanks Abdel. Do you know a proof of this fact ?

Comment: Darij, that is a very interesting reference. If you want the green chevron, then post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @loup blanc: were you paying attention? the paper I mentioned contains a proof of that fact.

Comment: Hi Abdel, I read the Arxiv version of your paper. In p. 11 there is a reference: [12]- Calan and Magnen- concerning the announced result ; yet, that is a personal communication.

Comment: I see. The arxiv version is quite different. The proof is in the published version indicated in the link above. If you do not have access to the journal and email me I can send you a copy.